# Restore default \raggedbottom footnote behaviour when using one of the Koma script classes

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes, koma-script

Using the standard LaTeX classes (article,...), footnotes are set directly below the text if the page is in `\raggedbottom` instead of `\flushbottom` mode. The KOMA script classes change this behaviour, i.e. the footnote is placed at the very bottom of the page even if the page contains only a few lines of text.

Here is a MWE for LaTeX article:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom
\title{\LaTeX{} article}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    A very short text.\footnote{A footnote.}
    \pagebreak
\end{document}
```

and here for KOMA-Script scrartcl:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom
\title{KOMA script scrartcl}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    A very short text.\footnote{A footnote.}
    \pagebreak
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE LaTeX article]
[image: MWE KOMA Script scrartcl]

Is it possible to restore the default behaviour (i.e. footnotes right below the text) without breaking the other footnote-related Koma script commands like `\deffootnote`, `\deffootnotemark` and `\setfootnoterule`?

Comment: A little late, but nevertheless: I can't reproduce the behaviour you are describing. Please Try to prepare a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Here's the MWE! ;-)

Comment: The behaviour is coming from `\pagebreak`, which isn't a good thing after all (if you don't know the difference between `\newpage` and `\clearpage`. Please inform yourself and decide, wheter `\pagebreak` is the way to go.

Comment: I don't see a difference between `\pagebreak` and `\newpage` in `\raggedbottom` mode. Could you provide some details why using `\pagebreak` isn't a good thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the `KOMA-Script` classes, the definition of `\footnoterule` includes a stretchable space of 0pt plus 0.05fil. Remove this additional space.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\footnoterule}{\vskip \z@ \@plus .05fil}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\title{KOMA script scrartcl}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    A very short text.\footnote{A footnote.}
    \pagebreak
\end{document}
```

[image]